# Android - 0 devices supported

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am having troubles updating my existing app. The apk upload works just fine, but Google Play says that there are 0 devices suported. I've been looking some other posts and tried to modify my manifest with no luck.

The app is developed with Ionic Framework. I have currently uploaded successfully more than 20 older versions. However today I'm stuck at this point.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="20000" android:versionName="2.0.0" package="PACKAGE" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="me.apla.cordova.AppPreferencesActivity" />
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
        </provider>
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService" />
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.ads.conversiontracking.InstallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And my graddle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Comment: what is the difference in manifest of previous version?

Comment: I compared the two versions and the changes are: versionCode, versionName and targetSDKVersion, which I don't know why is now 25. I tried to put 22 again with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a Google Play bug - there's a LOT of people with the same experience and apparently it can be ignored (and checked afterwards): [0 supported Android devices on Google Play app update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049269/0-supported-android-devices-on-google-play-app-update)

Comment: thanks! that was my conclusion. I will try an update later today

Comment: I've the same problem. I will launch and report the result here.

Answer (score 1):

did you add new dependencies in your App Gradle ? Sometimes this error came from a dependency not correctly added.

For example I added this library :

> compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

but in fact i should add it like this :

> compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

Also you can try to update all your com.android.support dependencies to 25.+ version and set your targetSdkVersion to 25 too.

Comment: I added no new dependencies on my graddle. I update my answer with graddle

Comment: Hi! Just tried that. I still have no supported devices

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the console developer. Today I'ved the same problem and launched with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug the Google Play Console engineers are currently working to fix it, no known ETA. I just wrote to Google after experiencing this too and this is all they could tell me. (I did suggest they provide developers with a notification to let them know of the issue).

Your code looks fine.

Fyi as of 20May17 the issue is resolved and should now work!