# 0 supported Android devices on Google Play app update

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

We are having trouble updating an existing app on Google Play. After uploading the updated APK on the Google Play Developer Console, I am seeing 0 supported Android devices on the 'APK details' window.

[image: Updated APK details]

[image: Previous build APK details]

The only differences in the 'AndroidManifest.xml' file are that the 'versionCode' and 'versionName' variables have been incremented.

The 'build.gradle' file has not changed at all since the last build.

I am starting to think this is an issue on Google's end but if anyone has a solution we would be very grateful.

Cheers!

Comment: you are not alone.. lot of folks getting similar errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play store is showing 0 supported devices with same code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045520/play-store-is-showing-0-supported-devices-with-same-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue earlier, it seems that the issue is with Google's frontend. I took a gamble and my app has rolled out fine for the exact same amount of devices.

I would imagine Google will sort the issue soon.

Good luck!

Comment: You're right! Tried rolling the app out anyway and lo and behold the update is available on 10,751 devices. Thanks!

Comment: I have spent too much time to find out error but error on Google play store that can not be imegine.