# No change in manifest and gradle but now on uploading apk showing 0 supported device

Tags: android, android-manifest, build.gradle

Earlier all the version were having no problem after updating android studio and uploading the app on play store it is showing supported device 0. The manifest and gradle are unchanged except the version name and version code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".services.MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">    
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".About" />
    <activity android:name=".AccessibilityPermission" />

    <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainNavigationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and my gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.zuts.notificationlogger"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: It's a temporary error in Google Play Console, dont worry about it, same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044686/android-0-devices-supported) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049269/0-supported-android-devices-on-google-play-app-update)

Comment: Thank You MatPag for the Help. Will try to upload the apk after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the apk anyway with 0 supported device. After few minutes the real figures were shown in supported device. Anyone with similar problem can rollout their apk in beta and can check if their problem is resolved.